# MongoDB, how to export json with mongoexport

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to execute

```
mongoexport --db Mydb --collection Items229900 --out D:/test.json
```

but it does not work

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export json from Mongodb using robomongo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28733692/how-to-export-json-from-mongodb-using-robomongo)

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: are you connected to mongod instance ?

Comment: I just type this command and robomongo validator displays "Error: Line 1: Unexpected identifier " at once . Way?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/cfdWh_uyeHZWV pic

Comment: @ЮрийСадовой instead of running `mongoexport` command in robomongo try to run on mongo shell

Comment: @yogesh I installed mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-ssl-3.0.3-signed
and
Tried to execute this in cmd: C:\Windows\System32>cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin
C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongoexport -d Mydb -c Items229900 -o It
ems229900.json
2015-05-26T15:01:16.895+0300    error opening output stream: open Items229900.js
on: Access is denied.

Comment: I tried this:

C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin>mongo.exe
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.3
connecting to: test
2015-05-26T15:21:16.286+0300 W NETWORK  Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.
2015-05-26T15:21:16.290+0300 E QUERY    Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed
    at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14)
    at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179
exception: connect failed

Answer (score 2):

Don't run this command on the shell, enter this script at a command prompt with your database name, collection name, and file name, all replacing the placeholders.

```
mongoexport --db (Database name) --collection (Collection Name) --out (File name).json
```

it works for me...

Answer (score 0):

The command is OK, just change destination path. Change "D:/test.json" to "D:\test.json".

mongoexport --db Mydb --collection Items229900 --out D:\test.json

Or just get rid of "D:\"

mongoexport --db Mydb --collection Items229900 --out test.json

Comment: Robomongo works on Usadovoy.st.local:27000, i can create DB, collections etc but when i try to run C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.0\bin\mongo.exe i get error:
MongoDB shell version: 3.0.3 connecting to: test 2015-05-26T15:21:16.286+0300 W NETWORK Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:10061 
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at connect (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179:14) at (connect):1:6 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:179 exception: connect failed

Comment: mongo usadovoy.st:27000/test where: "usadovoy.st" is hostname, "27000" is port address and "test" is database instance name.

Comment: There is my mongodb.org account and there is test too

Comment: are you executing this command at "usadovoy.st" server or at your local workstation ? This message "Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017"indicates that you are trying to connect to a local instance . Your original question is about using "mongoexport" .. was this issue resolved ?

Comment: Not get resolved. I cannot create connection at 127.0.0.1:27017 with robomongo, only Usadovoy.st.local:27000

Comment: In mongodb.org:
Connect to Your Deployment
To connect to this Mongod via the mongo shell:
C:\MMSAutomation\versions\mongodb-win32-x86_64-3.0.3\bin\mongo USadovoy.st.local:27000  //////// How to change from 127.0.0.1:27017 to  USadovoy.st.local:27000 for local default connect?

Answer (score 0):

Currently RoboMongo does not have this functionality of doing import/export of JSON data.

The shell that you have in RoboMongo is a 'mongo' shell, hence you cannot run utilities(like mongoimport, mongodump etc) from it. You can only run queries that are allowed in 'mongo' shell.

You can run this from command prompt in mongodb/bin : [mongoexport example](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#export-in-json-format)

There are other tools like [MongoChef](http://3t.io/mongochef) which support this functionality.

Comment: Thx. But json files is exported by MongoChef in undefined encoding. UTF-8, How to export in UTF-8?